# changing xaxis values using the ts function in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to construct a time series plot but my x-axis values are coming out as follows:

```
2021.0    2021.1   2021.2
```

I am working with daily data so how do i convert the values to either show me the dates individually.

please find in the image the code and the resulting plot

[image]

here is the sample data

```
structure(c(66588, 65998, 65169, 61602, 34027, 35742, 59925, 
71704, 75102, 75495, 69609, 80508, 32321, 70764, 79876, 75412, 
85663, 76178, 43812, 36239, 83926, 90303, 86982, 90570, 79069, 
47774, 49293, 82493, 89992, 100158, 84245, 85948, 44326, 38927, 
84494, 90638, 91097, 70238, 43515, 31359, 28645, 86979, 92625, 
86652, 93317, 71832, 37017, 35785, 82186, 73513, 73174, 85774, 
67636, 42980, 30624, 69381, 79719, 45178, 69105, 71137, 32572, 
28636, 72140, 79726, 69389, 68333, 66964, 28935, 24619, 77359, 
73295, 73380, 78886, 63430, 38911, 25200, 72715, 76692, 74592, 
85536, 67009, 40709, 30148, 75445, 79219, 82039, 76855, 76490, 
35819, 37498, 73453, 80486, 67467, 49768, 79670, 43520, 30434, 
78926, 95601, 83391, 37936, 66017, 39637, 37156, 52911, 85748, 
88092, 85149, 78700, 37948, 39846, 80609, 95367, 74042, 98832, 
82288, 44178, 38903, 87822, 115228, 73602, 79277, 64134, 33704, 
27804, 64903, 43836, 65163, 65165, 54556, 27783, 22703, 62504, 
54022, 53725, 57737, 48504, 20937, 17031, 45022, 57736, 52789, 
45591, 34339, 34126, 15271, 27592, 54517, 49757, 108732, 38091, 
18129, 18999, 41411, 48013, 42283, 40904, 37582, 20503, 15143, 
32316, 40716, 40054, 42159, 43033, 13893, 12085, 34885, 32443, 
39982, 33933, 31142, 13957, 14471, 37613, 41714, 36315, 33887, 
28388, 14404, 13103, 30872, 30671, 31024, 27345, 24699, 13210, 
10466, 24589, 27345, 26280, 25565, 21804, 12915, 9154, 14304, 
13771, 30891, 15951, 14314, 10615, 6645, 13406, 14780, 34407, 
11202, NA, 9458, 7884, -573, 36473, 24611, 19438, 15688, 8668, 
14423, 15395, 17756, 27527, 18578, 13466, 9004, 10425, 20528, 
17893, 15591, 18172, 16451, 8639, 6918, 7359, 7852, 14288, 15239, 
11250, 5738, 7446, 12969, 15609, 16853, 14502, 11716, 6204, 5797, 
13424, 17184, 15268, 11965, 10693, 6761, 3838, 6431, 14661, 13352, 
13321, 11866, 6115, 5638, 10948), .Tsp = c(2021, 2021.70684931507, 
365), class = "ts")
```

Comment: It will be difficult to answer definitively until you paste the output of `dput(myts2)`.

Comment: dput(myts2), i am not sure how to post a dput in stackoverflow but i think that did the trick?

Comment: You have to run `dput(myts2)` in R, then paste the output into your question (which you are able to edit).

Comment: ts objects don't really have a date associated with them. If you want to use timeseries and better plotting, use the tsibble package. For forecasting use fable as this is the followup package from the forecast package.

Answer (score 0):

ts does not have dates associated with it.  Convert your series to zoo or xts using the zooreg class, say, and then plot.  zoo has classic graphics, lattice graphics and ggplot2 methods.  zoo and xts objects  also work with dygraph.

If you want to fit it onto a single panel you are not going to be able to squeeze hundreds of dates individually on the X axis no matter what system you use but if you just meant using a date axis then that is easy to do and you can customize the axis further using the usual facilities of any of these graphics systems depending on what it is you want specifically.

```
library(zoo)
z <- zooreg(tt, start = as.Date("2021-01-01"))

plot(z)

library(lattice)
xyplot(z)

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(z)

library(dyraphs)
dygraph(z)
```